# How to send event appointment via SMS with ability to add it to user calendar?

Tags: sms, calendar

I want to send event's appointment (date and time) via SMS messages, I want the user to be able to click on it then Android will open the Calendar for them to add this event to their calendar.

For example, if I send the following address:

```
123 Main Street, New York, NY 10001
```

Android will display it as a link. If the user touched it, Android will take them to Google Maps.

I want to send a Title, Date and Time to the user, I want Android to display it as a link, if user touches it, Android show take them to Calendar app to add it to their calendar.

Comment: That should be possible from within the calendar app, where you can "invite" people to partitipate in an appointment. Have you tried that? Or is that approach for some reason not an option?

Comment: @Izzy That approach is not an option.